# Subtract string from an array of strings

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

I have an array `toggleableLayerIds` that refers to all three layers in my map. These layers are clickable links in the `#menu`.  On load, all of the layers are  *invisible*  (they each have a property called `invisibility` which can be set to either `visible` or `none`). In the code below, the layer that is clicked in the menu is assigned to the variable `clickedLayer`, which is then passed as a string to `map.getLayoutProperty.`  If it is visible, then clicking it makes it invisible, and vice versa.  So layers can be added on top of each other.

My objective is that when a layer is clicked in the menu, to make  *only*  that layer visible and set visibility to none for all other layers.  Basically, what I mean is that if there were a variable `var = unclickedLayers`, I would want to pass all strings in that array to `map.setLayoutProperty` and then set `visibility` to `none`.  Or, alternatively, if one layer is visible, to disable the the `map.setLayoutProperty()` function.

My question is, how would one "subtract" the `clickedLayer` from `toggleableLayerIds`, which could then be assigned a variable and passed to map.setLayoutProperty?

```
var toggleableLayerIds = ['parcel_06', 'parcel_11', 'parcel_16'];
for (var i = 0; i < toggleableLayerIds.length; i++) {
    var id = toggleableLayerIds[i];

    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = '#';
    link.className = 'active';
    link.textContent = id;

    link.onclick = function (e) {
        var clickedLayer = this.textContent;
        var unclickedLayer =
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        var visibility = map.getLayoutProperty(clickedLayer, 'visibility');

        if (visibility === 'visible') {

            map.setLayoutProperty(clickedLayer, 'visibility', 'none');
            this.className = '';
        } else {
            this.className = 'active';
            map.setLayoutProperty(clickedLayer, 'visibility', 'visible');
        }
    };

    var layers = document.getElementById('menu');
    layers.appendChild(link);
}
```

Comment: `var notClicked = toggleableLayerIds.filter(v => v != clickedLayer);`

Comment: thanks that worked!